# Iterating a selectlist to highlight an item, highlights each item in turn

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery method that iterates over a selectlist containing a number of options.  I want to hihlight the first line that has a match for some text typed by the user into a textbox named MMDCriteria.  Currently the code is selecting and highlighting each item in turn until it gets to the end of the list.

```
$("#MMDCriteria").bind('keypress', function(e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

            if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode                
                var criteria = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
                alert("");                
                $('select#MMD > option').each(function() {
                    var optionValue = $(this).text().toUpperCase();

                    alert(optionValue.substring(0, optionValue.indexOf(criteria)));

                    if(optionValue.substring(0, optionValue.indexOf(criteria)) > -1) {
                        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });
            }            
        });
```

I have only just started using jQuery so excuse the verboseness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highlighting multiple options because the `each` function is running for each option in the select list. You have to break out of the loop as soon as the first matching option is found by returning `false` . Modify the code roughly as:

```
..
var notFound = true; // 1) initialize a shared variable

$('select#MMD > option').each(function() {
    ..
    if(found a match) {
        ..
        notFound = false; // 2) update it's value to force exit from loop
    }
    return notFound; // 3) keep iterating until notFound is true
});
..
```

Alternatively, use a simple for-loop that keeps the logic clear.

```
...
var options = $('#MMD > option');
for(var i = 0; i < options; i++) {
    if found a match {
        add "selected" attribute
        return; // exists the `keypress` function immediately
    }   
}
..
```

Also, jQuery already normalizes the [event](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) object so you don't have to check for `keyCode` or `which`. The property will always be named `which`.